# Windows 8 brightness issue

Tags: windows-8, brightness

The problem I am facing is that when Windows is idle for some time, instead of dimming the screen, it turns on full brightness. I know this may be problem in power configuration somewhere but I cannot seem to find it.

UPDATE: I use a Sony VAIO VPCS116FA, Windows 8 Pro and I have installed latest NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: More information is required.  What brand of laptop?  Have you installed Windows 8 compatible drivers?

Comment: Updated with information from the comment above.

Comment: Are those the drivers from the nVidia website, or via Windows Update?

Comment: Sony VAIO support site.